# How to build libjpeg-turbo with Neon(SIMP) on odroid with linux environment

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, odroid, libjpeg-turbo

I am trying to use libjpeg-turbo with NEON enabled on odroid having linux environment.

I followed the instruction given in this http://cubieboard.blogspot.in/2013/02/raspbian-opencv-libjpeg-turbo.html post however didn't notice any change in image capture.(using libjpeg-turbo-1.5.1)

From this link  https://github.com/praveenofpersia/Pandboard-ES/wiki/Building-OpenCV-2.4.x-with-full-hardware-optimization-for-the-Pandaboard-ES i came to the conclusion that NEON has to be explicitly enabled using cflags.

Thus i looked through BUILDING.md in libjpeg-turbo there are instructions which provide cflags to enable NEON:

```
IOS_CFLAGS="-march=armv7 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon".
```

However these are for ios not for linux.

So can anyone suggest me how to include flags to enable SIMD(NEON) in libjpeg-turbo in odroid with linux environment.

Comment: What compiler are you using to build libjpeg-turbo? What is target CPU? If the answer is gcc and ARM, then -mfpu=neon is the way to go. Have you tried it?

Comment: odroid ux4 with ubuntu 14.04 and yes gcc compiler

Comment: It turns out that for ARM architecture with linux environment SIMD instructions gets enabled by itself ...so there is no need for explicitly adding any flag in configure file.

For other OS there are instructions mentioned in BUILDING.md in the source_folder to activate NEON instructions.